# How to get key from $Keys

Tags: javascript, enums, flowtype

In JavaScript there is no standard type of enum, I turned to the Flow documentation and found there the $Keys type, but the documentation does not describe how to get specific item in the "enum" lists. For example:

```js
const types = {
    T_HANDLE: 1,
    T_COMPUTED: 2,
    T_MATERIAL: 3
};

export type TYPE = $Keys<typeof types>;

class MyClass {
    type: TYPE;

    constructor() {
        this.type = 'T_HANDLE';
    }
}

let myObject = new MyClass();

if(myObject.type === TYPE.T_HANDLE){ //Flow: TYPE. type referenced from value position type TYPE
    // some
}
```

Or is there another way to implement the enum list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, `TYPE` is the Flow type that represents your enum options. It won't be available at runtime, so Flow is right to prevent you from using it like that.

Instead, you can use the enum key directly:

```
if(myObject.type === ('T_HANDLE': TYPE)){
  ..
}
```

Here, the `('T_HANDLE': TYPE)` part checks that you haven't mistyped the enum name.
Also note that if you only use string literals as "enums" like this, you don't actually need the `types` container for the values at all. This would work just as well:

```
export type TYPE = 'T_HANDLE' | 'T_COMPUTED' | 'T_MATERIAL';

class MyClass {
  type: TYPE;

  constructor() {
      this.type = 'T_HANDLE';
  }
}

let myObject = new MyClass();
if(myObject.type === ('T_HANDLE': TYPE)){
  ..
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I typically write my own Enum class like so:

```
class Enum {
    constructor(keys, start = 0) {
        return keys.reduce((obj, k) => ((obj[k] = start++), obj), {});
    }
}

console.log(new Enum(['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE'], 1));
```

Output: `{ GET: 1, POST: 2, DELETE: 3 }`

Comment: Given that the question is about Flowtype, this doesn't seem to answer the question?

Comment: @loganfsmyth indeed.